# Building a Filter function from OnClick Table row with react/redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So here is what I'm trying to do : I have a list of three name and when I'm clicking on one of them, the remaining two disappear. My final objective is to build a table so I can filter my data by clicking on the row. I don't really now where to start. I'm guessing that my OnClick Function should trigger some filter method on one of my redux store state. But I don't know how should I articulate this with my action and reducer. so I have at least two questions for now :

- What should  be my filter function ?
- How does this filter function works with my action/dispatch and reducer ?

I'm not asking for code or completed solution, I'm more looking for overall logic. Here is some parts of my code if needed for illustration :

My component :

```
class NameList extends React.Component {
                      constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                      }
                      render() {
                            var props = this.props.name;
                        return (
                  <div>
                                <ul>
                  { props.map((m, i) =>
                    <li key={i} onClick={???}>{m.name}</li>
                  )}
                </ul>
                </div>
                        )
                      };
                     }

        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
            return {
                name: state.nameData.allname,
            };
        };
```

My reducer :

```
var items = [
  { name: 'Louise', age: 27, color: 'red' },
  { name: 'Margaret', age: 15, color: 'blue'},
  { name: 'Lisa', age:34, color: 'yellow'}
];

  const nameData = (state = {
    allname: items
    }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_NAME':
        return {
          ...state,
          name: action.name
        };
          default:
            return state;
                }
              };
```

My action :

```
export function AuthorFilter() {
    return {
      type: 'SET_NAME',
      name,
        };
      }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use `mapDispatchToProps`. Then from within your component you would be able to dispatch suitable action.

If you want to get detailed explanation on how all these things are connected (store, action creators etc) you can check this article: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.md

Comment: thanks Adrien. I've Flag my question because I was unclear. I've almost solve my problem since then.